# Why the /users route in Express and Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Edit:** The default express app is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
----------------------------------------
These refer to files that look like:

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
------------------------------
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

However, the documentation says:

```
// this middleware will not allow the request to go beyond it
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Hello World');
})

// requests will never reach this route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome');
})
```

So my question, is why would a request ever make its way to the `/users` route when a default (i.e. `'/'`) route has already been specified? Is it because `routes` and `users` are not functions?

On a related note, why even specify the `/` if that is what is used by default each time?

Lastly, the default app specifies the `'/users'` route: Why not just put another path in the `index.js` route? I am confused how the app can specify `app.use('/users', users)` and then, in the users route, specify

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

What does the `/` correspond to? It seemed like all requests to `/` would be handled by the first route (the one that use the `routes` default file)

Comment: What are `routes` and `users`?

Comment: They refer to to the routes. There is a folder in the root named routes, it has two files, a users.js and index.js file.  I believe that `routes` defaults to `index.js` while `users` refers to the `users.js` file

Comment: The `/` in the users file is the index of the users route, i.e. `users/`. This makes resource handling very simple.

Comment: Where do you find any doc that `app.use()` let's you pass it a path and a folder?  It takes a path and a function.  The path is optional, the function is not.

Comment: Right...so somehow in the following: `app.use('/', routes);` routes is a function, even though I do not see it defined anywhere?

Comment: Is it not imported at the top of the file?

Comment: If you want to ask about code, you HAVE to show us all the relevant code.  And, if you can't find the code, then that's why you don't understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`app.use()` is middleware.  You pass it an optional path and a function and it is the function's job to decide if it wants to pass the request on to further middleware or further routes.  It does that by calling `next()` or if it doesn't want to pass it on, it doesn't call `next()`.

So, if you have:

```
app.use("/", fn);
```

That middleware will get called for all paths, but the code inside the function you pass it decides whether to pass the request on or not.

Comment: How do you pass on the request to the next piece of middleware?

Comment: @Imray - the third argument passed to the middleware callback function is a function reference (usually named `next` in the argument).  You call it to pass on the request to the next piece of middleware.

Comment: @Imray - you can also go here http://expressjs.com/api.html and look at the `app.use()` documentation.  Several examples there.  Also a good article on it here: https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/

Answer (score 5):

There are two routers in the Express 4 application skeleton: `routes` (mounted on `'/'`) and `users` (mounted on `'/users'`). You may use both of them or only `routes` or you may even add more routers.

app.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);  // please note the mounting point!
app.use('/', routes);
```

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please note that `router.get('/', ... )` for the `users` router means that the requested url is `http://yourserver/users` and not `http://yourserver/`